# 'Migration Meta Information' is not updating when I edit product title/name in magento 2.3

Tags: catalog, magento2.3, meta-title, meta-description, meta-keywords

**Previous question title:** same 'Migration Meta Information' is displaying for all product edit page in magento 2.3

**Edited question title:** 'Migration Meta Information' is not updating when I edit product title/name in magento 2.3

I have some products which are already added in my store. I have edited some of them, & I found that the 'Migration Meta Information' is the same for all these products.

When I add new product it seems fine. MEta title, Meta keywords, Meta Description are generated correctly for that product.

But when I edit any random product, 'Migration Meta Information' for the field MEta title, Meta keywords, Meta Description. 
If I added new product and then edit, it works fine

Is this an issue in 2.3 version of Magento or am I missing anything?

Please check the attached image
Here my product name is "WIDE DOMED 2-TONE CUFF BRACELET" but meta information is different.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @FaisalSheikh check the attribute set.

Comment: Ok Sir, and thank you for the response.